# What is following time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, indexing, time, time-complexity

If a for loop is defined as
`for (int i = 2; i < n; i = i*i + i)`
 What the
"i*2+i" represents for time complexity.
What is time complexity in big-O notation? 
How could I solve big-O notation for this increasing index?
Ex: i = 2 , 6 , 42 , 1086 , .... (general formula "i*2+i")

Comment: That loop index update has little effect on time complexity in O notation. However, you need to post more code since a nested loop's index makes a big difference.

Comment: The example looks like i²+i not `i^2+i` in C-syntax, which is it? E: you can write `i*i+i` in code blocks but no exponents

Comment: it is fixed. "i*i+i"

Comment: @hamzaygrtc You **need** to show us the body of your loop because it can change **everything**

Comment: OK, it's a tricky one, I think the loop makes O(log(log(n))) iterations, I'll leave the proof to you

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz: one can very well express the complexity of the number of iterations of the loop.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Of course you can, but is there a point in doing it? Won't the complexity of the loop be more interesting? Perhaps the OP is confused, thinking that the complexity of the loop **solely** lies in the definition.

Comment: Also @YvesDaoust about your answer. Just because an `int` is bounded you can't say is constant complexity, every data type in a computer is bounded, so according to your reasoning, any depenence on a bounded type will render the algorithm or that portion of it constant in time.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz: if the question is about the number of iterations, it is about the number of iterations. Maybe you pay $23000 per iteration, irrespective of the body.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz: that's exactly how it is. Whenever the problem size is bounded, even bounded by a Googolplex, we have a constant complexity. Review your theory.

Comment: If the answer is O(1) then this question wouldn't have been set as an exercise.

Comment: @harold: you can't be sure, can be a trap.

Comment: Could you look the above loop again. Just doing a thing and  I just need to prove loop complexity

Comment: Well @YvesDaoust, that is very true. Still, how can you explain the *bounded* argument? I've seen it and used it but for bounded input data size, there it makes sense, here not so much.

Comment: Not 100%, but about 99% yes. The code is illustrative, not meant to define the edge cases. All computer programs run in constant time or enter an infinite loop, it's not theoretically interesting.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz: ok, if you assume that n is by some magic unbounded, then the loop either makes at most a constant number of iterations (5 if I am right), or doesn't stop.

Comment: You can use the same argument to show that any program runs in O(1) time (or does not terminate), that's not what anyone ever means when they ask about the complexity of a code snippet, except as a joke.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's a bit shallow analysis. You're assuming `int` to be a 32 bit number, but this might not be the case, it depends on the computational model you use. Also, `n` can't be unbounded, it is a finite number in any computational model, its data type could be unbounded however. This would make the quadratic index update to have bigger time complexity than O(1). At best you can only say that, this particular loop in a 32 bit memory machine has O(1) in **average**.

Comment: Agreed with you @harold

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz: yes, I should have said with the current adoption of `int`. In the theoretical models, n is of course unbounded, as no asymptotic analysis would be possible otherwise. And a constant time for arithmetic operations can and is frequently used for unbounded operands, even though this is unrealistic (similarly, it is also assumed that exact arithmetic on reals is possible). But I don't understand why you say *on average*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `i` has a concrete type (`int`), it is bounded and the complexity is perforce `O(1)`.

In addition, the function is so fast growing that the capacity of an `int` is exceeded as of the sixth term.

---

If one considers that the given code is pseudocode and that the `int`s are unbounded, then one may use

```
i[k]² <= i[k+1] = i[k]² + i[k] <= a i[k]²
```

where `a` is a constant to be determined.

Then taking the base-2 logarithm

```
2 lg i[k] <= lg(i[k+1]) <= 2 lg(i[k]) + lg(a)
```

and by induction

```
2^m lg(i[k]) <= lg(i[k+m]) <= 2^m lg(i[k]) + (2^m - 1) lg(a) <= 2^m lg(a.i[k])
```

Taking the logarithm again,

```
m + lg(lg(i[k])) <= lg(lg(i[k+m])) <= m + lg(lg(a.i[k]))
```

also written

```
lg(lg(i[k+m])) - lg(lg(a.i[k])) <= m <= lg(lg(i[k+m])) - lg(lg(i[k]))
```

As `m` represents the number of iterations following the `k` first, for `n = i[k + m]` we have

```
lg(lg(n)) - lg(lg(a.i[k])) <= m <= lg(lg(n)) - lg(lg(i[k]))
```

In particular, with `k=0`, we can take `a = 3/2` and

```
lg(lg(n)) - lg(lg(3)) <= m <= lg(lg(n)) - lg(lg(2))
```

This proves `m = Θ(lg(lg(n))`.